# How do you make Direct3D work in a browser?

Tags: 3d, directx, browser-based-games, web

I've come across games that are 3D that are playable in a browser.  They require a plugin to be installed to work.  I guess the plugin creates a D3D window inside the browser.

How would I go about implementing something similar?

Comment: interesting question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unity web player (for windows) can use both DirectX and OpenGL in a window (however it abstracts your access to these APIs).

Another approach would be to implement a DirectX plugin using ActiveX (for Internet Explorer), or [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) (for other browsers).

If you use NPAPI, when your plugin starts up you'll receive a window handle where you can draw whatever you want (including a D3D window). If you go this route you're essentially running native code on the clients machines.

Comment: Note that the NPAPI is on its way to deprecation, so it's recommended that new web games use other technologies like WebGL (which is getting increasingly well-supported and does not require additional plugins)

Answer (score 5):

The game you are playing might use WebGL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL, or something more exotic like a firefox plugin, but I don't think you can embed machine code in a firefox plugin (I'm not sure, that would be a little security flaw).

Unity implements a web plugin version of their engine, and it seems they do so with ActiveX. I don't know if it implements on Mac..., I wonder though.

The best way to find out how this game you are playing use a 3D API or any other kind of plugin stuff, is to look at the HTML source of the page, and look for object or activex or else.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: For the ludicrous suggestion you can't "embed machine code in a firefox plugin." The entire point of plugins is to supplement web content with some set of "native" code.

Comment: well we can still discuss the dictionnary entries for addon, extension, plugin, mod, etc... It's still better to be precise about what does what...

Comment: And "plugin" is exactly what has, since Netscape Navigator 2, referred to executing unsandboxed (native or otherwise) code on the client machine.

Comment: netscape navigator 2, are you talking about a car, some kind of SUV ? I don't see any connection with the question ...

Answer (score 2):

Check out Firebreath for Cross-broswer support.

http://code.google.com/p/firebreath/